# MIPS Constructing Loops

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

Okay, so this might be a really silly question but I don't quite have the hang of Assembly yet. I have to write a program that calculates the summation of a series of numbers. It should behave like so:

```
Enter the first integer in the series: 5
Enter the number of integers in the series: 3
Enter the offset between integers in the series: 4

The series is: 5, 9, 13.
The summation of the series is 27. 

Would you like to calculate another summation (Y/N)? y

Enter the first integer in the series: 4
Enter the number of integers in the series: 5
Enter the offset between integers in the series: 27

The series is 4, 31, 58, 85, 112.
The summation of the series is 290.

Would you like to calculate another summation (Y/N)? Y

Enter the first integer in the series: -16
Enter the number of integers in the series: -22
There must be a positive number of integers in the series.

Would you like to calculate another summation (Y/N)? n
```

This is what I have so far:

```
li $v0, 4   #put 4 in as main parameter in v0
la $a0, Q1  #syscall will print string query 1
syscall
```

Store first integer in series in s0

```
li $v0, 5   #put 5 in as main parameter in v0
syscall     #syscall will read integer from Q1
move $s0, $v0   #move integer in v0 to s0
```

Request number of integers in series

```
li $v0, 4   #put 4 in as main parameter in v0
la $a0, Q2  #syscall will print string query 2
syscall
```

Store number of integers in series in s1

```
li $v0, 5   #put 5 in as main parameter in v0
syscall     #syscall will read integer from Q2
move $s1, $v0   #move integer in v0 to s1
```

Request offset of integers

```
li $v0, 4   #put 4 in as main parameter in v0
la $a0, Q3  #syscall will print string query 3
syscall
```

Store offset of integers in s2

```
li $v0, 5   #put 5 in as main parameter in v0
syscall     #syscall will read integer from Q3
move $s2, $v0   #move integer in v0 to s1
```

Set counter

```
li $s3, 1   #Set counter to zero
li $t0, 1   #iterator count is in t0
```

I'm just curious as to where to start my loop? And how exactly would I go about printing the entire series? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you do in "set counter" part, as the `s1` already contains number of series members.

And `s0` contains current element.

All you need (additional information) is to clear current_sum, let's say as `s3`:

```
add $s3, $zero, $zero   ; or "move $s3, $zero" if you prefer the pseudo-ops
```

So for your first example `s0`-`s3` will be set to `[5, 3, 4, 0]` before first loop iteration. This is everything ("world state") you need, any other value you will set up is probably some temporary for particular sub-task like displaying some value and similar, but as long as the core computation goes, these four values represent all you need, and everything else can be based upon them.

If `s1` is already less than `1` (`<=0` test), report wrong input.

Then the loop algorithm:

- add current element (`s0`) to current sum (`s3`) `; summing up all numbers`
- display current element (`s0`)
- `; handle the correct count of series' members`
- decrement counter `s1`
- if `s1` is zero, then goto exit_loop
- `; preparing for next loop iteration`
- add offset (`s2`) to current element (`s0`)
- display `", "`
- jump to first step

`exit_loop:` logic will involve printing end of line, summation text description, current sum value (`s3`), another new line(s) and asking for repeat y/n.

For example that 4 core values will evolve during iterations like this:

- `[5, 3, 4, 0]` => displays `"5, "` + all the updating of values
- `[9, 2, 4, 5]` => displays `"9, "` + all the updating of values
- `[13, 1, 4, 14]` => modifies `s3` to `27`, displays `"13"`, `--s1`, jumps to `exit_loop`

At `exit_loop` the core values are `[13, 0, 4, 27]`, code will display `27` as series sum.

Comment: I think I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. If the counter was equal to the number of ints in the series, it would go to the exit loop. The structure I was going for was something like: for i in range(x), first_int+(i*offset). I also totally forgot to put a string for the comma! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Bri usually "making it more complicated" is a sign of jumping into writing code too fast. Make sure first you have good high-level overview of the algorithms you will use, and also what are core data of the task (irreducible set of basic data, where removing any value will make the task impossible, as it can't be derived from the remaining ones) (like "model" in MVC programming design pattern). Usually these core values follow 1:1 the input data, or only few more are needed like iteration_number / time / keyboard_event. Also collect notes on any derived (and how) values. Write code after...

Comment: Working with assembly instructions is too tedious and takes lot of brain focus just for using the correct instruction in correct syntax and with correct registers, so it is usually better to reason about the task in the native language first, for a while, splitting it into simpler steps, and looking for any redundancies/similarities to extract them as subroutines/etc.

Comment: I think you're definitely right in my jumping into code too fast. I did not plan any of what I was going to do out, just tried to make it up as I went along--more importantly, before I even really understood the syntax of it. Very bad move on my part, and I'm glad I took a step back to look at everything because I was creating a mess.