# How to print the string at the end of the series in MIPS assembly language?

Tags: assembly, printing, mips, series

So I am trying to figure out how to print a series of integers with commas in between and a dot after the last integer in the series. This should look like this:
[How the series should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b03nq.png)

And this is what my output looks like:
[How the series looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcKP5.png)

How would I do that in MIPS assembly language?

Here is my code:

```
li $t0, 0
for:
bge $t0, $s1, endLoop
add $t1, $t1, $s0
move $s3, $t1

# Printing the series
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall
# Printing the commas
li $v0, 4
la $a0, S9
syscall 

add $s0, $s2, $s0
addi $t0, $t0, 1
j for
```

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? Just check whether the index is `2` and so print a dot not a comma. You seem to know how to use a conditional.

Comment: This what just an example. The user can vary the series length every time when Entering the number of integers in the series. How would I print a dot after the last integer in series? I have 2, 4, 6,...,n, instead of 2,4,6,...,n.

Comment: You still know the length of the loop, so you can test whether you are at the last one. Or, just let the loop run one less, and print the last one outside of the loop.

Comment: Not sure how much this will be of help with your problems, but somebody else is working on the same task: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42138807/4271923

Comment: Thank you, I have my program working. Just had to figure out how to place that dot at the end of the series.